# how to move a folder as subfolder within the same repository in github

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Eg:

parent->1.Test 
        2. source
I want test folder to move into source, How to move it in github web app? Can previous versions be tracked after moving?

Answer (score 0):

Just move your folder inside the source folder and if your app is already under `Git` version control, it will track this move as well and before moving things are already tracked in your previous commit.

There is nothing special which you need to take care, we move lots of folder while doing the code-refactor and its a very common scenario.

let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to move a folder.

Comment: you can simply move the folder using `mv` command if you are using `*.nix` operating systems.